# C# Interface, Unity, and Optional Parameter

Tags: c#, interface, optional-parameters

Hopefully someone can shed some light on this one.  I have an interface with an optional parameter.  We use Unity.  If I try to change the optional parameter in the method implementation, it works directly, but the Unity object uses the interface's default - not the implemented method's default.

Setup:

```
public interface ITestOptional   {
     string HappyMethod(string input, bool amHappy = false);
}

public class TestingOptional : ITestOptional   {
     public string HappyMethod(string input, bool amHappy = true) {
                if (amHappy) return input + " is Happy!";
                return input + " is Not Happy!";
     }
}
```

Add to Unity:

```
container.RegisterType<ITestOptional, TestingOptional>();
```

And Test:

```
//direct call
var testDirect = new TestingOptional();
string happyDirect = testDirect.HappyMethod("Cow", true);  //expecting happy - get happy
string sadDirect = testDirect.HappyMethod("Cow", false);   //expecting not happy - get not happy
string defaultDirect = testDirect.HappyMethod("Cow"); //expecting happy (default) get happy

//unity
var testUnity = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<ITestOptional>();

string happyUnity = testUnity.HappyMethod("Cow", true);  //expecting happy - get happy
string sadUnity = testUnity.HappyMethod("Cow", false);   //expecting not happy - get not happy
string defaultUnity = testUnity.HappyMethod("Cow"); //expecting happy (default) but get NOT happy.
```

Any ideas why the Unity object uses false as the optional parameter when the implementation uses true?

Comment: I don't want to sound critical but it seems *really* confusing to have that difference.

Comment: I completely concur on the confusion factor.  I planned to make the defaults match before curiosity got the better of me as to why it was doing this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<ITestOptional>();` returns compile type `ITestOptional`, so call to `testUnity.HappyMethod("Cow");` will be converted by compiler to use default value as specified in interface.

Similarly `new TestingOptional();` returns compile time `TestingOptional` and compiler will pick default from the class.

Possible solution (short of adjusting expectations/not using different defaults): you can resolve that type directly using Unity instead of resolving interfce (sometimes useful for tests):

```
  var directViaContainer = container.Resolve<TestingOptional>();
```

Side note: re-defining default values in class implementing an interface is not a god practice - you'll get into this confusing code often.

Comment: Concur on the "good practice" bit - the defaults should match for just this reason (confusing code) -- that confusion is what led me to post this in the first place.  I think if you change the default from the interface, it shouldn't be considered valid for that interface anymore - but that's a personal opinion, which could be wrong on several levels.

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with Unity. This is how C# compiler works. Optional arguments are filled in by the compiler at *compile time*. In the first example you call the `HappyMethod` method on the concrete type and that optional attribute is marked with `true`, so the C# compiler will fill in true for you. In the second example however, the C# compiler has no idea of the existence of the implementation, so it will look at the definition of the interface. And guess what: that interface is marked with `false`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the [`Resolve<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.practices.unity.unitycontainer.resolve.aspx) method, from an `IUnityContainer` instance. For sample:

```
var testUnity = container.Resolve<ITestOptional>();
```

Answer (score 0):

In your first example, your `testDirect` is an instance of type `TestingOptional`, for which you invoke its `HappyMethod` overload directly, using it's specified default parameter value of `true`.

In your second example, your `testUnity` is an instance of type `ITestOptional` and you invoke its `HappyMethod` that specifies a different default parameter value of `false`.

This is unrelated to how you created these instances. You would have observed the same if you had done:

```
ITestOptional x = new TestingOptional();
x.HappyMethod("Cow");
```